# OP claims to represent company in question

Tags: discussion, answers

[The author of this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/329976/88313) claims to represent a company asked about in the original question.  This user just joined the site 45 minutes prior to posting the answer.  They're currently listed as 'unregistered' on their SE profile.

I did a quick google search and there is someone with the same first name who works at the company they claim.

I can't say that the person posting this answer is the same person who works at that company.  Because of the nature of the question, I think if this person is who they say they are would lend credibility to the answer.  If not, the answer is deliberately misleading.

The privilege of reviewing first-time questions and answers according to [the guidance provided in the Help Center](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues):

> The purpose of this queue is to give special attention to users who may need to be educated on some aspect of our model and to posts that are more likely to need improvement.

I'm not sure how to guide this new user in a way that would improve their answer.  Is asking for proof they are who they say they are the best way?  Maybe asking them to update their profile with info and links that would help people evaluate their authority on the answer?

What would be the best approach to take for such a review in order to help a new user as well as others who might have similar questions.

Comment: Thanks for bringing this up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general I probably would put a "insufficient explanation" notice on the answer and add a comment explaining that "I'm from $COMPANY" doesn't add value to the answer and asking for verifiable sources for the claims/explanations provided in the answer.

PS: In this case the question itself needs some rework first.

Answer (score 6):

I think the part about being `from the Flipd team`is irrelevant.

On SE credibility is **NOT** based on your age, experience, or position in a company. It is based on your reputation. The user in question (as of this writing) has 1 reputation. Their answer should be interpreted and treated as such. (Not to say that low rep users can't write good answers, they can & do).

The user should be treated as if they were any other user. Same as if a user named `AppleEngineer123` answered a question and claimed to be an Apple Engineer. I would take them claiming to be an "Apple Engineer" as a grain of salt, especially if they are low rep.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and those are good points.  I think the part about being on the software team is relevant because it's how the answerer is stating knowledge on the subject matter.  I agree that if was just any low-rep user making the same statement then credibility would default to rep.  I also want to help the new user improve the answer, if possible.

Comment: @fsb Edited a bit. I'm unsure whether it should be removed or not.

Comment: I think the comment helps greatly and appreciate that someone from the company would choose to help clarify how they use MDM. It also lets me comment on their post to perhaps help them point to their documentation that Apple clearly says is the MDM responsibility. Even if Ana isn’t from the company - they aren’t trashing the company’s reputation so I see harm in deleting or editing and help in having that self-disclosure there. @nohillside is 100% correct - we shouldn’t worry about the answer until the question is fixed first.

Comment: @bmike I wouldn't want anyone to be inclined to upvote or to not downvote because Ana claims that she is from the company.